# Short story about people who lived only a few days

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Does anyone know the name of the short story in which the characters only lived a few days from birth to death? I believe it involved a ship where time was experienced normally. I recall the story plot from my younger days, but don't remember the author or the title.

Comment: Do you remember the media? Was it a book? Television? etc. You may want to also provide the rough time you read/saw it. "Your younger days" is kind of not helpful.

Comment: By 'younger days' Are we talking, 90s? 80s? Earlier?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/short-story-where-time-is-accelerated-and-characters-have-to-get-back-to-ship (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like ["Frost and Fire" by Ray Bradbury.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29)

Comment: One of my favorites; short but very evocative.

Comment: Without a doubt.  Loved this story.

Comment: There was even a movie made out of it, if I remember well.

Comment: @vsz - Yep; '[Quest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/combined)'

Comment: No question to my mind this is the answer, but maybe writing some more details about the story might make this a better answer.

Comment: @Broklynite which is why I decided to add my own answer. (I thought of "Frost and Fire" as soon as I read the title).

Answer (score 7):

[Quoting myself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53447/19561):

> Could it be Ray Bradbury's *Frost and Fire* (1946)? See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36883/19561).
>
> [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29):
>
> > Placed there by a past rocket ship that crashed, the people of the storied land are within sight of another rocket ship on a distant mountain plateau. The plot follows Sim, the protagonist of this story, and his apparently short life on a planet where people are cursed by radiation to live only eight days.
>
> You most likely read this in *[R is for Rocket](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?27227)*.

Once they're in the ship, they indeed do experience time normally:

> He could not believe it.
>
> Her first words were, "How long will this last?"
>
> He replied, carefully, "I don't know."
>
> "We are still young."
>
> "The ship. Its metal is around us. It cuts away the sun and the things that came from the sun to age us."
>
> Her eyes shifted thoughtfully. "Then, if we stay here—"
>
> "We'll remain young."

And they save some of their fellow men:

> The weeks passed. Generations lived and died in the cliffs, while the scientists and workers labored over the ship, learning its functions and its parts.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite "only a few days", but part of the plot of [Non-Stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Stop_(novel)) by Brian Aldiss is that

> the spaceship which the lead character and his tribe are living on is actually a generation ship which has returned to Earth orbit, with its inhabitants having developed to be smaller, move much faster, and die sooner.  Their slower "Giant" opponents are actually normal humans.