# Searching for title of movie about rapid aging

Tags: story-identification

People are born and grow up and die of old age in a matter of 5 days. The elders (5 days old) train children and send the most promising one on a trek across the dessert to a monolith that is the cause of the rapid aging to hopefully disable it.

I saw it on a reel to reel in the mid 90's. It looks like it was made in the late 70's or 80's. The cast was small. A few men played the elders seated in a row of chairs and the young boy who had to set out to save them who matures into a man and finally an elderly man.

I've been trying to figure out the title for years.

Comment: When did you see this movie? When do you think it might have been made? Any details about characters?

Comment: I saw it on a reel to reel in the mid 90's. It looks like it was made in the late 70's or 80's. The cast was small. A few men played the elders seated in a row of chairs and the young boy who had to set out to save them who matures into a man and finally an elderly man.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You MIGHT be thinking of [Quest (1984)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/), a movie based on Ray Bradbury's [Frost and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29).

In Frost and Fire, the life span is Eight days, and it's not the monolith (a space ship) causing the aging, but the radiation on the planet.  The hero goes on a quest to reach the ship, discovering when he does that inside of it (and, presumably, off planet) the unnatural aging ceases.

Unfortunately, I haven't see Quest, and it's rather hard to find info on it, online.

Comment: This sounds like it might be it. Ill try to see what I can find. Thank you.

Comment: @ashwood - You may want to look [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcb-M5a4Uy8); it looks like the whole movie is available on Youtube right now.  (Thanks to User15274)

Comment: That's it! You found it! Thank you. I've looking for it since I saw it in high school.

Comment: @ashwood -  No problem; don't forget to 'accept' the answer if it's correct :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an episode of Stargate: Universe that is modeled around this I think.  Is that possibly what you are referring to??

Comment: Name of the episode?

Comment: There also is a episode of the main Stargate:SG1 series, but people lived 30 days, not 5 (it's an episode where O'Neil begins to age rapidly because he caught the same virus as the inhabitants, and they have to figure out a solution)

Comment: @Kalissar In the Stargate SG-1 episode 1x09 *Brief Candle* - or 1x08, depending on if you consider the pilot to be two episodes - the Argosian race is engineered to live only 100 days. The accelerated aging is caused by nanites.

Comment: No it was definitely a film.