# YA sci-fi/fantasy book where people live in caves due to extremes of temperatures

Tags: story-identification

A society in a world where the the days are lethally hot and the nights are lethally cold.  People can leave their caves for a few hours in the morning and evening.  They are isolated, but one character decides to make a run for it, knowing it may mean his/her death.

Comment: Do you remember when and where you read it?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Burn-Out-Kristi-Helvig/dp/1606845691 only has extremely hot temperatures, and was a 2015 book, so it seems less likely...

Comment: This is almost certainly Frost and Fire (as mentioned in the answers below), and has been asked a number of times in different formats.  Often, people ask about the Movie based upon it '[Quest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/)' -- See [this question about the movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/searching-for-title-of-movie-about-rapid-aging/36895#36895), or [this search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Frost+and+fire%22) for various previously asked questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Frost and Fire, Ray Bradbury, 1946.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29

http://moodle.moreaucatholic.org/moodle19/pluginfile.php/45242/mod_resource/content/0/Frost_and_Fire_Word_doc_.pdf

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right answer rather than simply posting a link?

Answer (score 0):

The short story is called FROST AND FIRE by Ray Bradbury and was part of a collection of short stories in a book called "R IS FOR ROCKET" by Ray Bradbury. I have the Pan edition published 1972

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  This would be better suited as a comment, as you have provided additional information to the post by @DoscoJones!

Comment: Since Dosco hasn't elaborated on his or her answer, if you could provide a summary, it would be perfectly legit...