# Short film about a planet where people age very quickly

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I saw a short film online a few years ago that I'd like to watch again. I think the film itself is older - the video looked like it was ripped from VHS, and the special effects and production values were consistent with something made in the 80s or 90s. I don't think there were any computer graphics involved and it was probably shot on film. It was quite long for a short film, perhaps about 40 minutes in length. I'm fairly sure it was posted on [Boing Boing](http://boingboing.net), but I can't find the post.

The plot was that some people were stuck on a planet where people are born, grow old, and die within a very short space of time. (I can't remember how long - perhaps days or weeks, although it might be longer given that they could all learn how to speak.) To escape, somebody had to go on some kind of quest, which they'd been training for for generations, presumably because it was hard to complete before reaching the end of one's lifespan.

One scene in particular was a special effects sequence involving a pyramid with a set of moons orbiting a planet behind it - that sequence stuck in my mind.

It seems quite likely that the plot was based on a short story, in which case knowing the title of the short story would be helpful in tracking down the film.

Comment: Youre not thinking of the SG1 episode "Brief Candle" are you? It matches almost exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely the 1984 *[Quest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086162/)*, based on Ray Bradbury's "[Frost and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29)". It was the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36883/searching-for-title-of-movie-about-rapid-aging).

Summary of the short story:

> Placed there by a past rocket ship that crashed, the people of the storied land are within sight of another rocket ship on a distant mountain plateau. The plot follows Sim, the protagonist of this story, and his apparently short life on a planet where people are cursed by radiation to live only eight days.
>
> The people of this planet are also gifted with racial memory (they remember their ancestors' memories). However, they do not attempt to reach the sole remaining rocket ship due to the futility of attempting to reach it in one hour, which is the longest length of time between day and night (both deadly).
>
> Sim is then moved by the memory of his ancestors to find and meet with scientists who make halting progress towards the goal of lengthening the world's decreased life span. Sim, motivated by his dwindling days, makes it his goal to extend his life and reach the distant rocket, despite the protests of his sister and other cave-dwellers.

Film on Youtube:

The shot of the pyramid with the moons can be seen at the 16:47 mark.

Comment: This is it for sure, thank you!