# Short story where time is accelerated and characters have to get back to ship?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where time is accelerated on a planet.  The characters are actually born at the beginning of the story and then grow up quickly and inadvertently learn that their forebears came from a rocket ship nearby.  After having aged to "teenagers" they try to reach the ship?  At some point there is a war between confused aging survivors.

I think it was in a compilation which included a story called "Cousins".

Comment: Was this an older book (70s/80s) or more recent?

Comment: Cousins appear in these two anthologies:
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4195
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?318131

Comment: It was older, maybe 60s 70s 80s...  It was not Bradbury... I'm looking at the other links thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could it be Ray Bradbury's *Frost and Fire* (1946)? See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36883/19561).

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_%28short_story%29):

> Placed there by a past rocket ship that crashed, the people of the storied land are within sight of another rocket ship on a distant mountain plateau. The plot follows Sim, the protagonist of this story, and his apparently short life on a planet where people are cursed by radiation to live only eight days.

You most likely read this in *[R is for Rocket](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?27227)*.

Comment: Right!  This is it!  Thank you so much it is Bradbury.  I dropped the original book into a toilet in Cancun many years ago.