# What short story was about creatures with accelerated very short lives who also couldn't go in the sun?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story as a child about creatures that had accelerated lives and couldn't go in the sun. The day/night cycle was very short so you lived and died in the same location and one creature was desperately trying to go to a safer location.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this story, and did you read it in a magazine or an anthology? Also, when you say the creatures "couldn't go in the Sun", do you mean that they had an aversion to sunlight, like vampires?

Comment: @user14111: Almost certainly "Frost and Fire". You should make that an answer.

Comment: @user14111: Not all OPs ever accept an answer, but the likelihood increases if you post a 'real' answer rather than just a comment. I will upvote your answer if you make one, and I am sure many others will as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story about people who lived only a few days](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/short-story-about-people-who-lived-only-a-few-days)

Comment: @Todd Wilcox - [Andrew's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260936/122024) hasn't been confirmed to be correct by the OP yet, so it's a bit premature to flag this as a duplicate. Also, the thread you proposed as a dupe target doesn't have an accepted answer either. If and when Andrew's answer is confirmed to be correct by the OP, [this thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/short-story-where-time-is-accelerated-and-characters-have-to-get-back-to-ship) is the one that is currently being used as the dupe target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story where time is accelerated and characters have to get back to ship?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/short-story-where-time-is-accelerated-and-characters-have-to-get-back-to-ship)

Comment: @A Rogue Ant. - We only flag story-ID questions as duplicates when they have an answer that's been confirmed to be correct by the OP (via either an acceptance or a comment), and there's another question where the same story has also been confirmed to be the correct answer. [Andrew's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260936/122024) to this question hasn't been confirmed to be correct by the OP yet, so this question shouldn't be flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide the details on "Frost and Fire" since I agree that's the likely answer.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_(short_story)

**I read a story as a child about creatures that had accelerated lives and couldn't go in the sun.**

> The plot follows Sim, the protagonist of this story, and his
> apparently short life on a planet where people are cursed by radiation
> to live only eight days.
>
> The people of this planet are also gifted with racial memory (they
> remember their ancestors' memories). However, they do not attempt to
> reach the sole remaining rocket ship due to the futility of attempting
> to reach it in one hour, which is the longest length of time between
> day and night (both deadly).

**one creature was desperately trying to go to a safer location.**

> Sim, motivated by his dwindling days, makes it his goal to extend his
> life and reach the distant rocket, despite the protests of his sister
> and other cave-dwellers.

Comment: are not the "creatures" humans?

Comment: Humanlike, but not necessarily human, I think.

Comment: iirc, ancestors were humans who crashed on planet. since they have radically different physiology than ancestors, not just lifespan and accelerated maturity but also some kind mind-reading ability, u could argue that they were no longer human.

Comment: That sounds right.  It's been decades since I read it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wAh27YJprI -- never had heard of this film version.